# On Heroku, is it possible for a single app to have multiple environments?

Tags: heroku

I would like to have at least two environments on Heroku for the same app, so we can use one of them for testing. Is it possible for a single app to have multiple environments? Or must we have multiple apps and treat each one of them as a different environment?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Heroku Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines). That way, you can fork your existing app, and have e.g. "Development" and "Staging" versions (in addition to "Production"), all connected in a pipeline. 
You can define separate environment variables for each of the apps in the pipeline.
You can then git push e.g. to your Development app, and "Promote" the compiled slug from Development, to Staging, to Production.